# Using a Loop to Copy and Paste

Tags: vba, loops, copy, paste

I am a beginner VBA coder and have been trying to figure out how to work a loop within my spreadsheet. I am attempting to declutter a collection of loan information I have, but just as a basic framework for the specifics of my question, I have generated the following random numbers in Column ("A:A") in the first Worksheet of the Workbook:

5
241
4
5
648
87
65
74
52
1

The loop I'm using is:

```
Sub LoopTest()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10 
    Range(i,1).Select.Copy Destination:=Range(i,5)
Next i
```

So essentially I am trying to copy the first cell in Row 1, Column 1 and paste it to Row 1, Column 5 and then loop to Row 2, Column 1 and paste it to Row 2, Column 5, etc. etc. until I loop through Row 10. Preferably, I would like to loop from the first row data to whatever is the last row of data (and I'm aware that is possible) but I am unaware how to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why you would need to do this by row. Couldn't you copy A1:A:10 and paste it to E1:E10 instead? This would keep you from having to loop. If you were to copy then you could do it with a Range.Copy call:

Range("A1").Copy Range("E1")

This copies A1 to E1.

Comment: True, I could just copy and paste it with a simpler sub function but I was attempting to practice looping with a very basic premise so that I would be able to build it to a more complicated process. My goal is to loop through the data I have, execute a mathematical equation, then paste to another cell and loop through each row of data.

Comment: I understand now that it is a learning exercise. If you want to manipulate the data then it would be better to set a variable to the value in the cell, perform your calculations, then set the value to the new cell equal to the new value.  Setting a value to a variable can be done like this (assuming that your sheet to be manipulated is titled Sheet1 and the new value is supposed to go into cell E1):     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = newValue